# How to extract specific items from a nested list and append to new column?

Tags: python, r, dataframe, networkx, nested-lists

I have a dataframe, that has a column which contains nested lists. I am struggling to get the usernames extracted from these nested lists (I am quite new to this).

Dummy data:

```
myNestedList <- list("1" = list('username' = "test",
                              "uninteresting data" = "uninteresting content"),
                     "2" = list('username' = "test2",
                                "uninteresting data" = "uninteresting content"))
Column1 <- c("A","B","C")
column2 <- c("a","b","c")
mydf <- data.frame(Column1, column2)
mydf$nestedlist <- list(myNestedList)
```

I would like to extract all usernames for each row and append them to a new column, if there is more than one username for a row, the second/third/n-th username should just be appended with a seperating ",".
I have tried something like `sapply(mydf$nestedlist,` [[`, 1)` but this just gives me one list of the entire column "nestedlist".

For context: I am trying to build a directed graph for further use in Networkx or Gephi. The data in column1 are the nodes and the usernames are mentions, hence edges. If there is another way of doing this, without extracting the usernames from the nested list, this could also be a solution.

Thanks in advance for any help! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we know the nested level, can use `map_depth`

```
library(purrr)
 mydf$username <- map_depth(mydf$nestedlist, 2, pluck, "username")
```

-output

```
> mydf
  Column1 column2                                                nestedlist    username
1       A       a test, uninteresting content, test2, uninteresting content test, test2
2       B       b test, uninteresting content, test2, uninteresting content test, test2
3       C       c test, uninteresting content, test2, uninteresting content test, test2
```

---

Or if it is not known, then apply with a recursive function with a `condition` check to find the 'username'

```
library(rrapply)
mydf$username <- rrapply(mydf$nestedlist,  
    condition = function(x, .xname) .xname %in% 'username', how = 'prune')
> mydf
  Column1 column2                                                nestedlist    username
1       A       a test, uninteresting content, test2, uninteresting content test, test2
2       B       b test, uninteresting content, test2, uninteresting content test, test2
3       C       c test, uninteresting content, test2, uninteresting content test, test2
```

---

If we want to `paste` them, use

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
mydf$username <- rrapply(mydf$nestedlist,  
    condition = function(x, .xname) .xname %in% 'username',
          how = 'bind') %>% 
        invoke(str_c, sep=", ", .)
 mydf
  Column1 column2                                                nestedlist    username
1       A       a test, uninteresting content, test2, uninteresting content test, test2
2       B       b test, uninteresting content, test2, uninteresting content test, test2
3       C       c test, uninteresting content, test2, uninteresting content test, test2
```

-structure

```
> str(mydf)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Column1   : chr  "A" "B" "C"
 $ column2   : chr  "a" "b" "c"
 $ nestedlist:List of 3
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ 1:List of 2
  .. .. ..$ username          : chr "test"
  .. .. ..$ uninteresting data: chr "uninteresting content"
  .. ..$ 2:List of 2
  .. .. ..$ username          : chr "test2"
  .. .. ..$ uninteresting data: chr "uninteresting content"
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ 1:List of 2
  .. .. ..$ username          : chr "test"
  .. .. ..$ uninteresting data: chr "uninteresting content"
  .. ..$ 2:List of 2
  .. .. ..$ username          : chr "test2"
  .. .. ..$ uninteresting data: chr "uninteresting content"
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ 1:List of 2
  .. .. ..$ username          : chr "test"
  .. .. ..$ uninteresting data: chr "uninteresting content"
  .. ..$ 2:List of 2
  .. .. ..$ username          : chr "test2"
  .. .. ..$ uninteresting data: chr "uninteresting content"
 $ username  : chr  "test, test2" "test, test2" "test, test2"
```

Comment: Great, this worked! However using your first solution (purrr), the results in the new column "username" are also lists. Using `mydf$username_clean <- unlist(mydf$username)` throws an error. Is there a way to modify your solution in order for it to not return a list?

Comment: @Cold2Breath If there are more than one element, do you want to `paste` it

Comment: @Cold2Breath i updated the post by `paste`ing the elements to create a vector

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! For some reason `rrapply ` is not available, even though I am using R 3.9. 
However, I was able to clear the rest using regex! :)

Comment: @Cold2Breath you may use `rapply` from `base R` but with some modificaitons though.  I used `R 4.1.0`

Comment: @Cold2Breath: `rrapply` should be available from CRAN for R >= 3.5, R 3.9 doesn't exist though, perhaps you meant R 2.9? (that would be quite old)

Comment: Yes, my bad, confused by Python with my R-Version there for a moment. I am using R 4.0.2